# Remove attribute from Json response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rest, response

I have a REST service whose response structure differs on certain attributes based in request. From my code I return different class objects(not ActiveRecord objects) based on response to be sent to controller. From response that controller gets, certain attribute need to be passed as header in response. But that should be deleted from response body. How can I delete that from class object?

Suppose my response to controller could be class1 object with attributes : attr1, attr2, attr3

Now attr3 should actually be in response header, so this works:
response.headers["Headertitle"]=attr3

But my json response should only have attr1, attr2.

Another situation could be that response to controllers is class2 object with attr1, attr3, attr4, attr5. attr3 from this also goes to response headers. And again response should not have attr3.

Value of attr3 depends on some business rules and differs on request. But every response needs to have attr3 in response headers and not in body.

How do I remove attr3 from response?

I have already tried :

format.json { render :json => json_response.to_json(except: ["attr3"])}

And this does not work.

Comment: Define "does not work"

Comment: Meaning attr3 is still in response.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Ruby Hash slice](http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/slice) method:

```
all = {name: "Zulh", email: "zulh@example.com", phone: "0123456789"}
=> {:name=>"Zulh", :email=>"zulh@example.com", :phone=>"0123456789"}

selected = all.slice(:name, :email)
=> {:name=>"Zulh", :email=>"zulh@example.com"}

selected.to_json
=> "{\"name\":\"Zulh\",\"email\":\"zulh@example.com\"}"
```

Or, if you prefer [except](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/Hash/except), here is the correct way to do it:

```
all = {name: "Zulh", email: "zulh@example.com", phone: "0123456789"}
=> {:name=>"Zulh", :email=>"zulh@example.com", :phone=>"0123456789"}

selected = all.except(:phone)
=> {:name=>"Zulh", :email=>"zulh@example.com"}

selected.to_json
=> "{\"name\":\"Zulh\",\"email\":\"zulh@example.com\"}"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Rails 5.

You can do the following:

```
    def send_auth_token_for_valid_login_of(user)
      render json: { user: user }, :except =>  [:password_digest, :token_created_at, :reset_password_token, :reset_password_sent_at]
    end
```